# Disable Remote authentication for SOLR Urls General

Tags: solr, bitnami

I'm running `Bitnami SOLR` 5.5.5.1 latest version on Windows 10.

From a website I'm doing a call to the SOLR like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/my_index/select?q=*&rows=1000.
```

Some limitation on my website prevent me to specify authentication credentials. In previously versions of Bitnami SOLR you didn't have to pass any authentication.

How can I disable authentication completely?

Answer (score 3):

Hi Bitnami developer here,

We added a basic authentication method for security reasons but you can remove the LocationMatch section that you will find in the file at installdir/apache-solr/conf/solr.conf.

Please note that you'll need to restart the Apache server after modifying that configuration file.

I hope it helps.
Jota

Comment: Thanks a lot; it solved the problem; much appreciated